# How to get a good binary classification deep neural model where negative data is more on dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I wanted to make a binary image classification using Cifar-10 dataset. Where I modified Cifar-10 such a way that class-0 as class-True(1) and all other class as class-False(0). Now there is only two classes in my dataset - True(1) and False(0).

while I am doing training using the following Keras model(Tensorflow as backend) I am getting almost 99% accuracy. 
But in the test I am finding that all the False is predicted as False and all True are also predicted as False - and getting 99% accuracy.

But I do not wanted that all True are predicted as False.

I was expecting that all True are predicted as True.

How can I resolve this problem?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

output=model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

Comment: You will have to train with a better dataset....

Comment: @Attersson, If I have True:False data ratio 1:1 then it works fine. The problem arise If I have more negative data.

Is that mean That I need to use always balanced data?

Comment: Yes in order to train your neural net. Maybe not 1:1 but more balanced, you get the point

Comment: Google for "class imbalance", which is a *huge* subtopic in the ML field...

Comment: @desertnaut it's a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. Get more data with `True` label. However in most scenarios this is not easily possible.
2. Use only a small amount of the data that is labeled `False`. Maybe it is enough to train your model?
3. Use weights for the loss function during training. In Kerasyou can do this using the [`class_weight` option](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) of `fit`. The class `True` should have a higher weight than the class `False` in your example.

As mentioned in the comments this is a huge problem in the ML field. These are just a few very simple things you could try.

Comment: Thanks for good answer. I think the 3rd option make more sense for my problem.